# Sort Map by value in java

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

My goal is to have is given a map of  to return an ascending array/list of sorted key values. For example:

Input: the Map containing the following key/value entries separated by a space:

```
"Apple" 10
"Orange" 8
"Kiwi" 15
```

Output:

```
{Orange;Apple;Kiwi}
```

The only other approach I could think of was creating a `Map<Integer,Set<String>>` and then sorting by the key which is fairly convoluted. I got this approach to work but it seems rather inefficient in terms of code and logic. Thanks so much!

Comment: How about using comparator?

Comment: Detailed explanation of answer to your question is present here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Answer (score 2):

One technique is to push the Map into a List, and then use a Comparator to sort the values before putting that back into a Map.

e.g., something like:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = 
            new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(mapYouPassedIn.entrySet());
```

Then you can use Collections.sort() plus a Comparator to do the grunt work over this list.

Comment: I'm a little confused how to use a Comparator to sort this list. Could you expand further? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I just have to get more familiar with java interfaces. Just a beginner in java

Answer (score 1):

In **java 8** there is a very simple approach to this using streams:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        map.put("A", 2);
        map.put("B", 3);
        map.put("C", 1);
        System.out.println(map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

prints [C, A, B]

Comment: this doesn't compile for some reason...

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: it is java 8. what is your compiler version?

Comment: @Exbury Java 8 has been out for quite a while now. Do we really need to keep qualifying answers with it?

Comment: That's odd. I do have Java 8. javac 1.8.0_31 to be exact

Comment: I get the Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @user3750474 I edited the code a bit: I was using a method reference instead of a direct method call. Can you try it again using `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`? I've tried this myself and it works for me.

Comment: Error: The method sorted(Comparator<? super Map.Entry<String,Double>>) in the type Stream<Map.Entry<String,Double>> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<Map.Entry<Object,Comparable<? super Comparable<? super V>>>>)
 Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Comment: That's surprising. I'm using a map to integer rather than double but I can't see why that should matter. I'll post my test program in the answer - cut and paste that to a new project and see if you get the same error.

Comment: How can I ? 1. Print Value with key
2) Can we sort the values in descending order?

Comment: Not sure if its sorting for printing or not. After your SOP, when I print again, it shows original map. Does it require to be in new map? if yes how?
 
System.out.println(map.toString());

[C, A, B]
{A=2, B=3, C=1}

Answer (score 0):

You can get entrySet from hashMap and sort Map.entry list.
eg:

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry
<Integer,    Integer>>( map.entrySet() );
    Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> comp = 
new   Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>()
    {

        @Override
        public int compare( Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2 )
        {
            return ( o1.getValue() ).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
        }
    };

    Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> cmp1 = Collections.reverseOrder( comp );
    Collections.sort( list, cmp1 );
```