# Sort a list having map as input

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list which as elements those are map i want to sort this list over map element value

```
[{id=45964953, count=1}, {id=46009636, count=1}, {id=45936991, count=1},  {id=45984035, count=2}, {id=45951961, count=1}, {id=45399668, count=31}]
```

I need to sort it on count value. Can it be done in java

Output should be like this

```
[ {id=45399668, count=31},{id=45984035, count=2}, {id=45964953, count=1}, {id=46009636, count=1}, {id=45936991, count=1}, {id=45951961, count=1}]
```

Comment: Come on guys using the search function cannot be that difficult. The same question was asked and answered already today (and in the past). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163279/sort-map-by-value-in-java

Comment: Smells like homework to me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that implements `Comparable<Map<String,Integer>>` (assuming `String` and `Integer` and the key and value of your Map) and compares two Maps based on your criteria.

Then you can pass your list and your Comparator to Collections.sort().

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has been out for some time. Impress your teacher with this:

```
list = list.stream()
    .sorted((m1, m2) -> Integer.compare(m2.get("count"),m1.get("count")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Here's some test code:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>() {{
    add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{put("id",45964953); put("count", 1);}});
    add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{put("id",46009636); put("count", 1);}});
    add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{put("id",45936991); put("count", 1);}});
    add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{put("id",45984035); put("count", 2);}});
    add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{put("id",45951961); put("count", 1);}});
    add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{put("id",45399668); put("count", 31);}});
}};                      
list = list.stream().sorted((m1, m2) -> Integer.compare(m2.get("count"), m1.get("count"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[{count=31, id=45399668}, {count=2, id=45984035}, {count=1, id=45964953}, {count=1, id=46009636}, {count=1, id=45936991}, {count=1, id=45951961}]
```